# electrum CLI - 'daemon is not connected'

Tags: linux, electrum

I installed [Electrum](https://electrum.org/#download) on my Raspberry Pi.

Then, I ran `electrum create` to make a wallet.

Then, I ran `electrum daemon start` to start the background process.

I'm currently trying to query the balance of my wallet (should be 0) from the command line using `electrum getbalance`

I get this error

```
[root@fish ~]# electrum getbalance
daemon is not connected
```

Daemon status:

```
[root@fish ~]# electrum daemon status
{
    "blockchain_height": 352760,
    "connected": false,
    "nodes": [
        "electrum.thwg.org:50002:s",
        "kirsche.emzy.de:50002:s",
        "ecdsa.net:110:s",
        "erbium1.sytes.net:50002:s",
        "electrum.drollette.com:50002:s",
        "eco-electrum.ddns.net:50002:s",
        "EAST.electrum.jdubya.info:50002:s"
    ],
    "server": "electrum.be",
    "server_height": 0
}
```

Note the `"connected": false,` field. What does this mean? Is it related to my node not working?

Answer (score 2):

you need to run

```
electrum daemon load_wallet
```

load_wallet or other wallet